Azure API Manager behind frontdoor with Mutual TLS (mTLS)
Public traffic of our application is currently routed through frontdoor Premium and then forwarded to API MANAGER where it is forwarded to the service running on kubernetes.
One issue I have is the using cheaper versions of API Manager (e.g basic), VNET integration is not included meaning API Manager will be publicly accessible
I have put it some security steps which include:

APIM is secured with a subscription key
APIM requires a front door ID Header X-Azure-FDID, otherwise 403 is returned (in extreme cases this can be brute forced)
It is also theoretically possible that one may also find out the real IP of API Manager and bypass frontdoor (if this happens they require to brute force (1,2))

All 3 of the above points are pretty secure by themselves so I think its very unlikely that one is able to bypass all 3.
As the last layer of security, I am considering implementing mtlS (mutal TLS) between frontdoor and APIM.
After alot of research I am not sure if frontdoor does support mTLS. As far as I read all traffic between frontdoor and API manager is encrypted with https but I want to configure APIM to ensure that it responds to requests only coming via frontdoor so that I am 100% sure the the connection is encrypted and filtered via front door.
Can you tell me if this is possible and guide me to any documentation? Specifically I am also interested in how this can be accomplished via the portal or using terraform. Also out certificates expire after 3 months and are automatically rotated so I want to ensure that there is no downtime between APIM and frontdoor when the certificate is rotated.
Any help will be appreciated
Side note: Instead of mTLS, I think we can also whitelist the azure front door IP addresses, but given that this is extensive and it can change, I think this approach is risky. Also we are unable to whitelist ServiceTags as we do in Load Balancers.

Are you still facing the same issue. @Michele

I have never managed to setup mutal tls but instead have added a firewall policy which whitelists only azure front door IP addresses. I guess this extra rule does improve security but it will be nice and more secure to implement mutal tls if this was supported
